# data.match(var) not working it seems

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok so I have this small block of code, which is supposed to scan a number on a website, but for some reason I have a hunch that it's not scanning at all.

```
var Regex = /\<span class="currency-robux" data-se="item-privatesale-price">([\d,]+)\<\/span\>/;
                    var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex);
                    PriceSelling = Number(PriceSelling.replace("," , ""));
```

Is there anything wrong with what I have on this?

This is connected to an `if` statement

```
if (PriceSelling <= PriceWanting) {
```

which from there calls a function to run, but for some reason it doesn't seem to ever run. So I think the `Regex` is wrong but am not sure how. (`PriceWanting` has a variable; this is just a snippet from the code itself.)

On the website, this is what I'm trying to extract.

```
<span class="robux " data-se="item-privatesale-price">115</span>
```

Keep in mind that the `item-privatesale-price` changes, which is why I have it set to capture that data.

Comment: BTW: Why you escape `<` and `>` characters (`\<`, `\>`? This is unnecessary since they are not have special use in Regexps

Comment: @hindmost Because this is scanning a number on a website, and to make the computer understand where they are, I've decided to put that in, maybe if I take it out, think that will help?

Comment: your regex should match something like <span class="currency-robux" data-se="item-privatesale-price">12345</span> do the numbers on the website have any formating (spaces or other chars?)

Comment: Well thing is the item-privatesale-price changes, so I need the scanner to scan that number, which is why I have it set to that ([\d]+)

Comment: this has class `"robux "`, not `"currency-robux"`

Answer (score 2):

You regex is generally fine, but you are using the result in the wrong way. If it matches, it will return a result containing the full string, and the matched number. not just the number. You just need the number, which is match index `1`, so you can use `PriceSelling[1]`.

Also in your edit you are matching on a `span` with `class="robux "` which obviously is different to your regex. If you are just interested in `data-se="item-privatesale-price"` you can change it to match a tag with that attribute within it.

```
var data = '<span class="robux " data-se="item-privatesale-price">115</span>';

// matches a span with the data-se attribute within it
// i.e. appears before the closing >
var Regex = /\<span[^>]* data-se="item-privatesale-price"[^>]*>([\d,]+)\<\/span\>/;

var PriceSelling = 0;

var PriceSellingMatch = data.match(Regex);
if(PriceSellingMatch != null) {
    PriceSelling = Number(PriceSellingMatch[1].replace("," , ""));
}
```

Comment: Your variable naming advice is good, but just for the record the constructor is `RegExp`.

Comment: Yeah that was dumb of me

Comment: But now I'm getting a 'unexpected token if' ah going to have to debug some more now lol.

Answer (score 1):

The class in your regex ex is wrong you are looking for:

```
/\<span class="currency-robux" data-se="item-privatesale-price">([\d,]+)\<\/span\>/
```

but the regex should be

```
/\<span class="robux " data-se="item-privatesale-price">([\d,]+)\<\/span\>/
```

look at the difference on the class attr value

Comment: Ok well I managed to fix that, but the if '(PriceSelling <= PriceWanting){' Still doesn't seem to work, not sure why.

Comment: see Rhumborl answer, he is just a faster typer

Answer (score 0):

Regexes aren't good for parsing HTML, you can do something like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = YOUR_HTML_STRING;

var price = parseInt(div.querySelector("[data-se='item-privatesale-price']").innerHTML);

console.log(price);  // => 115
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wezzfokm/2/)